# Why is my app crashing in System.Windows.ni.dll on startup with no useful stack trace? (seemingly after adopting Caliburn.Micro)

Tags: windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

1. Start with the default "empty" Windows Phone App project (Windows Phone 8). Let's call it `BlackAdder` for fun.
2. Add Caliburn.Micro from Nuget
3. Move `MainPage.xaml` to the `Views` subdirectory and create a matching ViewModel in `ViewModels\MainPageViewModel.cs`
4. Fix the namespace for `MainPage` to `Blackadder.Views` in both the `.xaml` and `.xaml.cs` files
5. Update `App.xaml`

   ```
   <Application
   x:Class="BlackAdder.App"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
   xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BlackAdder">

   <Application.Resources>
       <local:Bootstrapper x:Key="bootstrapper"/>
   </Application.Resources>

   </Application>
   ```
6. Update `App.xaml.cs`

   ```
   public partial class App : Application
   {        
       public static PhoneApplicationFrame RootFrame { get; private set; }

       public App()
       {
         InitializeComponent();

        // Show graphics profiling information while debugging.
         if (Debugger.IsAttached)
         {
             ...
         }
      }
   }
   ```
7. Create `Bootstrapper.cs`

   ```
   public class Bootstrapper : PhoneBootstrapper
   {
     private PhoneContainer container;

     protected override void Configure()
     {
       container = new PhoneContainer();

       container.RegisterPhoneServices(RootFrame);
       container.PerRequest<MainPageViewModel>();

       AddCustomConventions();
     }

     protected static void AddCustomConventions()
     {
     }

     protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
     {
       return container.GetInstance(service, key);
     }

     protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
     {
       return container.GetAllInstances(service);
     }

     protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
     {
       container.BuildUp(instance);
     }
   }
   ```

When we run the app, it crashes in a very weird place.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

There is no inner exception, and the stack trace is (seemingly) useless.

`System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()`
`System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority)`
`System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(object context)`
`System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(object[] args)`
`System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ni.dll!System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(System.IntPtr pHandle, int nParamCount, System.Windows.Hosting.NativeMethods.ScriptParam* pParams, System.Windows.Hosting.NativeMethods.ScriptParam* pResult)`

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this has nothing to do with caliburn.micro at all. The problem lies in `Properties\WMAppManifest.xaml`.

After moving `MainPage.xaml` to the `Views` subdirectory, the `Navigation Page` setting (found on the first tab, `Application UI`) needs to be updated to `Views\MainPage.xaml`